# Why is this homogeneous function a polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

Suppose function $f$ is $k$-homogeneous function defined on the set of $r\times r$ complex matrices with $f(gAg^{-1})=f(A)$, where $g\in GL(r,\mathbb{C})$. Then why is $f$ a polynomial?